# Form is submitted even if minlength is unmet

Tags: html, forms

I noticed, that a form containing an `<input>` element is submitted, even if the `<input>` has a `minlength` attribute.

F.e. in my attached code, submitting works when no value is entered, but it fails if the length of the entered value is less than fife.

Why does it behave like this?
In my opinion the browser should prevent a submit when the minlength requirement is not met.

```html
<form>
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" minlength="5">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nature of minlength.

By adding `minlength="5"`, the value must either be empty or five characters or longer to be valid.

If you want to avoid empty case you need to use `required`.

More details here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/minlength

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it behave like this?

… because it was designed that way.

If a field is required then make it `required`.